# Trigger function to refresh Postgres materialized view and capture refresh end time?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I am trying to build a summary table in our Postgres database that contains information about when various materialized views were refreshed. I would also like this table to trigger the actual refreshes.

The desired format for the table is as below, call it `mv_refresh_monitor`:

| view_name | refresh_time_start | refresh_time_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| view_one | 2022-02-01 22:10:59.234567 | 2022-02-01 22:11:59.234567 |

The table shows `view_one` was last refreshed late at night February 1st, and the refresh took 1 minute to complete.

What I would like to do is trigger the materialized refreshes by updating the `refresh_time_start` field; doing so would trigger the materialized view in the `view_name` field to refresh, and then also update the same row's `refresh_time_end` field to capture the time when the refresh is done.

My current implementation uses a function (to update the monitor table), a trigger function (to both refresh the view and call the function), and a trigger on the monitor table to call the trigger function. This is scoped only for a single materialized view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "ingested_digital_spend"."timestamp_refresh_end"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."void" AS $BODY$
        UPDATE schema.mv_refresh_monitor SET refresh_time_end = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles';
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "schema"."refresh_materialized_view"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
BEGIN
IF NEW.view_name = 'view_one' AND NEW.refresh_time_start IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.refresh_time_start THEN
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view_one;
        PERFORM timestamp_refresh_end();
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "refresh_mv" AFTER UPDATE ON "schema"."mv_refresh_monitor"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "schema"."refresh_materialized_view"();
```

This almost works, but I'm trying to improve / fix three things:

1. Make this parameterized so that I don't have to write new `IF THEN END IF` clauses in the trigger function each time I add a new materialized view to the schema.

   - This seems like it shouldn't be terribly hard, I just haven't figured out the right way to parameterize PL/pgSQL functions yet.
2. Currently the time recorded in `refresh_time_start` and `refresh_time_end` are identical, despite the refresh operation itself taking 80 seconds. I am not sure how to scope the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` operations so that they don't evaluate to the same timestamp when the trigger function is initially called.

   - This feels like it should be possible, but I'm not as sure of this.
3. I would like the actual refresh to happen "in the background" if possible. That is, for the UPDATE to complete immediately and release the session that is performing the UPDATE. Right now the transaction on the monitor table doesn't complete until the view REFRESH transaction itself completes, so the client session hangs until the refresh completes.

   - This might be impossible.

Any suggestions or solutions for getting closer to these three requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way by pushing to much into the trigger/function. I would go with:

1. A function that you provide the view name and start name to. It does the `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW some_view>` and updates `mv_refresh_monitor` with information. For information on how to parametrize this see [Dynamic Queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)
2. For the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` issue see [Current date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT). `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` by design captures the timestamp at the start of a transaction and does not change in the transaction. You are looking for `transaction_timestamp()/statement_timestamp()`.
3. If you don't tie the `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` to the `UPDATE` you eliminate this issue.

Comment: Thank you Adrian -- very helpful thoughts.

For point #3, I am guessing that means it's impossible to have the client perform the `UPDATE` transaction that triggers the `REFRESH` without the client being on the hook for waiting for the `REFRESH` to finish. Is that correct? Is there any other mechanism for a client to initiate a `REFRESH` without needing to wait for the `REFRESH` transaction to finish? (Even outside the requirements as they're laid out here?)

Comment: A function runs in its own transaction so everything inside of it will run in that transaction. You will need to wait for `REFRESH` statement to finish however it is run. The best you can is to do it in its own connection/session.